# how use onsubmit event

Tags: html, events, onsubmit

Good afternoon

when disabled the javascript in my navigator, the event onsubmit is not execute .

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="miformulario" name ="miformulario" onsubmit="alert('prueba 123')" >
    <input type="submit" value="aceptar" name="btsubmit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Alert is a JavaScript function. Why would you turn of JavaScript anyway, if you are developing?

Answer (score 0):

**onSubmit** is a java script event. Disabling java script does effectively disable the handling of all java script events.

**alert()** is a java script function. So even if the event would have fired - the alert would not appear.

There is no way to circumvent this.